# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tween' of undefined - Masterslider.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am using Master Slider and There are Three Slider in a Single Page.
Also I am using Fullpage.js

```
var slider = new MasterSlider();
slider.setup('masterslider', {
  width: 300,
  height: 300,
});
```

```
slider.control('lightbox');

slider.control('slideinfo', {
  insertTo: '#staff-info2'
});    
$(document).ready(function() {        
  $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();    
});

var slider1 = new MasterSlider();
slider1.setup('masterslider1', {
  loop: true,
  width: 220,
  height: 420,

});

slider1.control('arrows');
slider1.control('slideinfo', {
  insertTo: '#staff-info'
});

var slider2 = new MasterSlider();
slider2.setup('masterslider2', {
  loop:true,
  width:240,
  height:240,
  view:'flow'
});
//  slider.control('arrows');
slider2.control('slideinfo', {
  insertTo: '#staff-info1'
});
```

These are the calling for these three slider every thing is working finer but there are console error for the 'tween' of undefined
This is the line where the error is define in the masterslider.js file

```
    p.__show = function(ele){
    ele.appendTo(this.$element).css('opacity','0');
    CTween.fadeIn(ele , MSSlideInfo.fadeDuratation );
    if(ele[0].tween)ele[0].tween.stop(true);
    this.current_ele = ele;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sliderinfo` looks for an element within the slide with a `ms-info` class and then show it in a `div (staff-info1);`

Either you remove `slideinfo` info configuration or add `ms-info` class into each slide. 
slider2.control('slideinfo', {
  insertTo: '#staff-info1'
});

Example
...

```
  <h4 class="ms-layer ms-info stext7" style="left: 130px; top: 470px;" data-type="text" data-duration="900" data-delay="2500" data-ease="easeOutExpo" data-effect="bottom(40)">
 this is a slide.
                </h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

ele is a 0 length array. ele[0] is undefined. You need to change the line

> if(ele[0].tween)ele[0].tween.stop(true);

to

> if(ele.length > 0 && ele[0].tween)ele[0].tween.stop(true);